# Ubuntu GTK+ 3 desktop app, made with Python library PyGObject

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just created my first GTK+ 3 app with Python using [PyGObject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is very nice to be able to make GTK applications using Python, as I love that language. I'm not completely sure if the way I designed the code is the most conventional and efficient way, so would like some people with more experience to take a look at it.

It's a very simple app that can temporarily disable the automatic screen lock when your screensaver kicks in. Sometimes when I am watching a movie with my partner and we pause it to get some food, my screensaver kicks in and the computer is locked and I need to re-enter my password again. This is a bit annoying sometimes, so I made this little tool that temporarily disables the screen lock and enables it again after some time, so that my computer isn't left insecure.

Here's the code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, GLib



class ScreenLockDisableWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__(title="Screen lock disable")

        self.screensaver_settings = Gio.Settings('org.gnome.desktop.screensaver')
        self.initial_lock_enabled = self.screensaver_settings.get_boolean('lock-enabled')
        self.main_ui_stack = Gtk.Stack()
        self.quantity_input = Gtk.SpinButton.new_with_range(min=1, max=60, step=1)
        self.unit_radio_minutes = Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget(None, "minutes")
        self.unit_radio_hours = Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget(self.unit_radio_minutes, "hours")
        self.time_left_label = Gtk.Label()
        self.seconds_left = 0

        self.set_border_width(25)

        self.add(self.main_ui)

    def start(self):
        self.show_all()
        self.reinit_main_ui_stack()
        self.connect('destroy', self.exit)
        Gtk.main()

    def exit(self, app):
        self.screensaver_settings.set_boolean('lock-enabled', self.initial_lock_enabled)
        Gtk.main_quit()

    @property
    def main_ui(self):
        self.main_ui_stack.add_named(self.screen_lock_ui, 'main')
        self.main_ui_stack.add_named(self.timer_ui, 'timer')
        self.main_ui_stack.add_named(self.already_disabled_ui, 'already_disabled')
        return self.main_ui_stack

    def reinit_main_ui_stack(self):
        if self.seconds_left > 0:
            self.main_ui_stack.set_visible_child_name('timer')
        elif not self.screensaver_settings.get_boolean('lock-enabled'):
            self.main_ui_stack.set_visible_child_name('already_disabled')
        else:
            self.main_ui_stack.set_visible_child_name('main')

    @property
    def screen_lock_ui(self):

        header_label = Gtk.Label(halign=Gtk.Align.START)
        header_label.set_markup('<big><b>Screen lock</b></big>')

        description_label = Gtk.Label(
            halign=Gtk.Align.START,
            label="Disable the screen lock for:"
        )

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=10)
        box.add(header_label)
        box.add(description_label)
        box.add(self.time_picker)
        box.add(self.start_button)

        return box

    @property
    def time_picker(self):

        self.quantity_input.props.value = 1

        radio_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        radio_box.add(self.unit_radio_minutes)
        radio_box.add(self.unit_radio_hours)

        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.add(self.quantity_input)
        box.add(radio_box)

        return box

    @property
    def start_button(self):
        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Start")
        button.connect('clicked', self.on_start_button_click)
        return button

    def on_start_button_click(self, button):

        self.screensaver_settings.set_boolean('lock-enabled', False)

        quantity = int(self.quantity_input.get_text())

        if self.unit_radio_hours.get_active():
            minutes = 60 * quantity
        else:
            minutes = quantity

        self.seconds_left = minutes * 60
        self.update_time_left_label()
        self.reinit_main_ui_stack()

        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(1, self.update_seconds_left)

    def update_seconds_left(self):

        self.seconds_left -= 1
        self.update_time_left_label()

        self.update_lock_enabled()

        return self.seconds_left > 0

    def update_lock_enabled(self):
        if self.seconds_left < 1:
            self.screensaver_settings.set_boolean('lock-enabled', True)
            self.reinit_main_ui_stack()

    def update_time_left_label(self):
        self.time_left_label.set_text(f"{self.seconds_left} seconds")

    @property
    def timer_ui(self):

        header_label = Gtk.Label()
        header_label.set_markup("<big><b>Screen lock disabled</b></big>")

        message_label = Gtk.Label("Enabling screen lock again after:")

        enable_now_button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Enable now")
        enable_now_button.connect('clicked', self.on_enable_now_button_click)

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=10)
        box.add(header_label)
        box.add(message_label)
        box.add(self.time_left_label)
        box.add(enable_now_button)

        return box

    def on_enable_now_button_click(self, button):
        self.seconds_left = 0
        self.update_lock_enabled()

    @property
    def already_disabled_ui(self):
        return Gtk.Label(
            halign=Gtk.Align.START,
            label="The screen lock is already disabled"
        )


ScreenLockDisableWindow().start()
```

Some things I'm a bit confused about:

- I put the `Gtk.main()` and `Gtk.main_quit()` inside my window class. Not sure if this makes sense. If there are multiple window classes, how would GTK know which window to show?
- I used the `Gtk.Stack` widget to switch between views in the app. Is this the way to go, or would you normally use `hide()` and `show()` on the widgets? Seems to me that's more cumbersome. Also I noticed that `hide()`, `show()` and the `Gtk.Stack.set_visible_child_name()` methods don't seem to work in `__init__()` but do work in a callback function, from a button click for example. That's why I put the `reinit_main_ui_stack()` method in the `start()` method that is called after `__init__()`.
- Is there a way to add/remove widgets after initialization? Or re-render a widget so that you can give it new contents? I am coming from web development and am used to libraries like React where you have a `render()` method that re-renders the complete content of the component when it is called again, so you can easily set a new state, which re-renders the component, and in the render function you can have different content rendered with a different state. I guess that's not the way it is done in GTK+.